# Transformation of graphs

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

Let $f(x)=(3x-5):(x-2)$

a) Find the value of constants $p$ and $q$ such that $f(x)=p+ q:(x-2)$.

b) Hence describe a single transformation which transforms the graph of $y=1:x$ to the graph of $y= f(x)$.

I am in second grade IB student on SL. I have problems especially with the point a). I tried to put sign equal between $(3x-5):(x-2)$ and $p+q:(x-2)$ and do it by algebraic method but I found myself having 3 unknowns. Then I tried to think about it as transformations to the functions $1:(x-2)$ but it did not work either so I have no idea what to do :(

Thank you

Comment: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: I am in second grade IB student on SL. I have problems especially with the point a). I tried to put sign equal between (3x-5):(x-2) and p+q:(x-2) and do it by algebraic method but I found myself having 3 unknowns. Then I tried to think about it as transformations to the functions 1:(x-2) but it did not work either so I have no idea what to do :(

Comment: You may also have a look at [How to ask a homework question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question).

Comment: I use Mathematics Standard Level for the IB Diploma, Cambridge. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
  (3x-5):(x-2)&=p+\frac{q}{x-2} & \text{multiply all by $x-2$}\\
  3x-5 &= p\cdot (x-2) +q\\
  3(x-2)+1&= p\cdot (x-2)+q
\end{align*}
Hence $p=3$ and $q=-1$.